# Databricks - Unable to run databricks-connect. Get Access Denied

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I am using JRE - 1.8 and databricks-connect version 9.1.15 with python version - Python 3.7.9

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)

Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00)
```

I see that command - databricks-connect always returns below error even when I invoke commands-
databricks-connect configure or databricks-connect test

```
 "Access is denied."
```

I do not receive prompt for configuring cluster details.
Did I miss anything in configuration?

Note- databricks cli is working fine with above setup